# Prevent server from accessing network share

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have built a test environment I want to isolate from my production servers.

As part of this I want to prevent my new server from accessing file/network shares on production.  For example prevent it from accessing   \\MyProdServer

I updated my host file with
`0.0.0.0    MyProdServer`

However this doesn’t work I can still access the files.  I do not have firewall available nor do I want to edit my production server in anyway.

Comment: the server is running a web service, this web service tries to save files to a share. I have updated the config to point to a new share. Put it is possible that the old config is put back on to the server. In which case want to ensure the system will not automatically copy files to production

Comment: How do you *not* have a firewall available?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, @NathanC.

Comment: we want test server to be identical to production. Production does't use a firewall (at the moment) that is another issue.

Comment: @Daveo The only way you're going to get this to work properly is with a firewall. Even if you have it up to *only* isolate it.

Comment: @NathanC thanks I might have to give it a try - does windows firewall allow blacklisting like this

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to skin this cat. The most obvious way would be to have tight deployment practices and never allow credentials for the production server to get deployed to the test environment.

Second option - create egress rules on the test environment's firewall that blocks all traffic to the production server.

Honestly, if you're *that* concerned about this, the two environments really should be on separate networks, separated by appropriate network ACLs.

Comment: We have tight deployment practices however we do a sync every 24 hours from prod to test to it could one day potentially brake and somehow override local settings. 

With the firewall the production server doesn't have its firewall on and we want the test server to match production as much as possible. And do not have time/approval to change production at the moment. Looking for something quick and simple

Again we do not have budget for seperating networks. Looking for a 5 min solution.

Comment: Well, *something* is going to have to change. With the constraints you specified, the most foolproof way of doing this at the moment is one of the two options I specified. You **don't** have to change production. Set a firewall rule on test and be done with it.

Comment: Also, your "might someday brake[sic]" clause is problematic. There are **thousands** of things in your environment that "might someday break". Do you feel the need to account for each and every one of them? You have a problem **right now** that needs a solution. So solve it as best you can now, and then revisit when you have the time, say, to put in a proper network.